# `npm audit` found vulnerability in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've started making a habit of regularly checking `npm audit` on most of my projects, and if I find one of my dependencies has a vulnerability I either try to patch it for them (via pull request) or report the issue (via GitHub issue)

However I recently installed a package and noticed some really quirky behavior:

```
$ > npm install --save fingerprintjs2

+ fingerprintjs2@1.8.0
added 564 packages from 744 contributors and audited 4667 packages in 6.341s
found 9 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 moderate, 2 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
$ > npm audit

                       === npm audit security report ===

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Out-of-bounds Read                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ stringstream                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.0.6                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > libcipm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp >  │
│               │ request > stringstream                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/664                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Out-of-bounds Read                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ stringstream                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.0.6                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > node-gyp > request > stringstream     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/664                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Out-of-bounds Read                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ stringstream                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.0.6                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > request >  │
│               │ stringstream                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/664                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Out-of-bounds Read                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ stringstream                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.0.6                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-registry-client > request >       │
│               │ stringstream                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/664                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Out-of-bounds Read                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ stringstream                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.0.6                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > request > stringstream                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/664                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ http-proxy-agent                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.1.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-profile > make-fetch-happen >     │
│               │ http-proxy-agent                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/607                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.2.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-profile > make-fetch-happen >     │
│               │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/593                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > cli-table2 > lodash                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ fingerprintjs2                                               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-audit-report > cli-table2 >       │
│               │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 9 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 moderate, 2 high) in 4667 scanned packages
  9 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

At first glance it looks like `fingerprintjs2` may have many poor dependencies, but looking closer at the specific dependencies -- ***all of the vulnerabilities are reported to be within npm itself!***. Worse yet, they all seem to be basically the same 3 dependencies

**stringstream**

- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > libcipm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > request > stringstream`
- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > node-gyp > request > stringstream`
- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > request > stringstream`
- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-registry-client > request > stringstream`
- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > request > stringstream`

**http-proxy-agent**

- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-profile > make-fetch-happen > http-proxy-agent`
- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-profile > make-fetch-happen > https-proxy-agent`

**lodash**

- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > cli-table2 > lodash`
- `fingerprintjs2 > npm > npm-audit-report > cli-table2 > lodash`

I didn't get this strange behavior from ***any*** of my other packages (I've installed `vue`, `vuex`, `vue-router`, `jquery`, `bootstrap`, `fontawesome`, `sha1`, `express`, `gulp`,.... just ***tons*** of stuff -- but I've never seen this) so I knew that it had to somehow be related to FIngerprintJS

Looking at their package.json file for a lead, they actually have **no dependencies**, and only a handful of devDependencies (all build tools):

```
{
  "name": "fingerprintjs2",
  "version": "1.8.0",
  "description": "Modern & flexible browser fingerprinting library",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "browser",
    "identification",
    "fingerprint",
    "fingerprinting",
    "privacy"
  ],
  "author": "Valentin Vasilyev",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2",
  "main": "dist/fingerprint2.min.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-standard": "^10.1.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "standard": "^10.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "specs/phantomjs.runner.sh specs/spec_runner.html",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "lint": "standard --fix"
  },
  "standard": {
    "ignore": [
      "specs/lib",
      "specs/phantomjs-testrunner.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

### What is going on here?

I've tried upgrading NodeJS (now on version `v10.4.0`) and NPM (now on version `6.1.0`) but it didn't help.

The only clue I have is the following:

```
$ > npm ls npm
test-audit@1.0.0 /home/sbarnett/src/test-audit
└─┬ fingerprintjs2@1.8.0
  └── npm@5.10.0
```

For some reason FingerprintJS seems to require NPM version `5.10.0` even though I have `6.1.0` installed. I have no idea why it would require this version, though, as there's no mention in the package.json file

### Update

Whatever the cause was of this strange bug, it's no longer happening when I start a new project and install `fingerprintjs2` - so I believe one of the dependencies of `fingerprintjs2` was updated and corrected the issue